# Python Dataframe add new row based on column name

Tags: python, pandas

How do I add a new row to my dataframe, with values that are based on the column names?

For example

```
Dog = 'happy'
Cat = 'sad'
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Dog', 'Cat'])
```

I want to add a new line to the dataframe where is pulls in the variable of the column heading

```
      Dog   Cat
0   happy   sad
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `append`:

```
df.append({'Dog':Dog,'Cat':Cat}, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     Dog  Cat
0  happy  sad
```

Comment: `append()` is removed in pandas 2.0. The docs say: "Removed deprecated `Series.append()`, `DataFrame.append()`, use `concat()` instead ([GH 35407](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407))"

Answer (score 0):

You can use append in a different way(other than mentioned above one)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df

output:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
df.append(df2)

output:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  5  6
1  7
```

Comment: `append()` is removed in pandas 2.0. The docs say: "Removed deprecated `Series.append()`, `DataFrame.append()`, use `concat()` instead ([GH 35407](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407))"